# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I generated the script using Gradle. After i am running script in gradle. it throwing error

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone can u give me any solutions with clear steps.

Comment: There's not enough information here to go on.

Comment: We need more information to help you here. maybe you're sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: No Rene, i haven't used any proxy setting